# Looking for a progression of learning to get back my math skills

Tags: self-learning

I am an professional that has rarely used math over the last 20 years. Well, anything outside a spreadsheet and basic formulas.

My son, who is quite bright, is now getting to an age where I am finding it difficult to help him with this studies. So, I want to relearn what I lost. From what I remember, the progression is Pre-Algebra, Algebra, Geo., Trig., Pre-Calc, Calc... That right? Any new and fun ways to learn? Just pick up books and go for it?

I am doing this for me and him, so either way, I going to try. Just want to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: Are you looking for the standard college prep high school track or starting earlier?

Comment: College prep would be great.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend the Khan Academy exercises, and in particular their [Knowledge Map](https://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard). You can start by trying the exercises at any point on the map, and based on whether you do well or not, either move further down, or back up towards any rusty prerequisites.

Comment: I second this suggestion. Khan Academy uses videos and interactive quizzes to guide and track learning, and the breadth of their courses is incredible. I use modules from their courses for summer work and to develop myself, for instance by completing their computer programming series.

Answer (score 2):

Schaum's Outlines are great.  First Year College Math covers algebra 2, trig, analytic geometry and precalculus.  I would hit algebra 1 and geometry first though.  Also, older books are often better if you get the classics.  Usually they have all the answers, so self study is aided.  I don't know Khan Academy, but if it is basically programmed learning, I endorse it.