# Relearning Mathematics

Tags: self-learning

During K12 I had problems understanding maths because in most cases I could not understand how it would be useful or what its applications are. I passed K12 maths mostly by memorizing the process to get a correct answer. Now at 32 years, it is starting to hinder my growth. I see the beauty of what I have lost and would like to go back and educate myself with these k12 foundations of maths and physics so that i can be ready to tackle the more complicated stuff.

I'm may be more of a "creative type" but my hobbies, interests and profession do get technical (Architecture, Synthesizers, Music, Computers). So, to aid in my relearning process, Can you recommend resources (preferably books) that will help me?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Is this question especially different from earlier ones? Clicking on the "self-learning" tag yields [**MESE 11021**](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/11021), for example.

Comment: Hi  Benjamin, thanks for your reply. I did not see that post, i am new to the site. There is only two replies and one recommendation to that post and it is khan academy, i am more interested in books if you or anyone knows any. thanks!

Comment: FWIW, you can try the online mathematics exercises that I have created: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/folder-student-exercise-tasks-for-mathematics-language-arts-etc---autocorrected.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to learn. Do you want something like a textbook, or something that gets you thinking but doesn't 'cover' all of one subject necessarily.

It's a very personal question. *Measurement*, by Paul Lockhart is lovely, but it might be too hard for your first adventure. You might like [Steven Strogatz's *The Joy of X*](http://wordplay.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/11/26/joy-of-x/?_r=0). Once you find one book you like, it will help you find others.

If you want a textbook, you might enjoy *Mathematics: A Human Endeavor*, by Harold Jacobs. (Older editions will be inexpensive.)

Comment: Thank you so much Sue, I'm so glad you replied! That looks like exactly what I need!!! Bless you so much!!!

Comment: Which did you like, the textbook or the others?

Comment: I like them all, thanks again! I don't know which one I am going to start with. So far I think I'm going to start with The Joy of x then A Human Endeavor and lastly Measurement since you said it might be too hard for my first adventure. But in the mean time until I get my books I'm going to watch Introduction to Mathematical Thinking with Keith Devlin. which I also saw you recommend.